# Modifying date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I want to modify a date adding 5 days, and setting hour/minute/second to 0:0:0.

For example, current
`2016-03-13 21:21:21` to `2016-03-18 00:00:00`

But using

```
moment().add(5, 'days').toDate()
```

I got `2016-03-18 21:21:21`.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `moment().startOf('day').add(5, 'days').toDate()`

this way you set the date to `0 hours` , `0 min` and `0 sec`

Comment: This is good, but it's slightly safer to add days *first*, then move to the start of the day.  This is because not all local days start at midnight, such as the day that DST starts in Brazil, when the day starts at 1:00 AM.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `setHours()` function as follows:

```
moment().add(5, 'days').toDate().setHours(0,0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
var date = moment().add(5, 'days').hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).toDate();
```